# Twilio dtmf input being duplicated when number is dialed via tel: uri

Tags: dtmf

I have an application that generates a QR code for a user to scan which contains a phone number & access code that the user can dial to join a conference call. When some users scan the QR code with the iPhone to "dial" the number and access code, the dtmf input is duplicated. So an access code that is 123456 is comes back as 11223344566 on the backend (some inputs are duplicated and others are not)

For example:

1. Value of said QR code is 809-555-1234,123456#
2. Users scans QR code with their phone and clicks the number to dial
3. Number is dialed correctly, TwiML is delivered that request an access code
4. GATHER receives input from user but that input is received as 112233445566

I've noticed that not all number are duplicated 100% of the time. It seems that numbers are randomly duplicated. If the access code after the `,` is 123456 I may get 112334556 or 1223344566 ect ect

This issue appears to be limited only to iPhone with Verizon as the carrier. Any possible chance this is a Twilio issue? URI scheme of the number to dial is following proper ISO standards. This has worked for years but only broke for me in the past 2-3 weeks. I have attempted adding more `,` characters between the phone number and access code but the problem remains. If I added a `,` character between every number of the access code the problem goes away but there is about a 2.5 delay between the entry of every input which is not desireable.